# Animação com animate css3

Tags: html, css, animate

Estou montando uma animação com o animate css3

```css
.img-minibox{
 height:auto;
 max-height: 200px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left:-40px;
}
ul li{
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
<ul>

                  <a href=''>
                    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
                      <div class='img-minibox'>
                        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150' class='img-responsive'>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </a>
                  <a href=''>
                    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
                      <div class='img-minibox'>
                        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' class='img-responsive'>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </a>
                  <a href=''>
                    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
                      <div class='img-minibox'>
                        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x250' class='img-responsive'>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </a>
                  <a href=''>
                    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
                      <div class='img-minibox'>
                        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x250' class='img-responsive'>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </a>
                </ul>
```

a animação funciona mas o que eu quero fazer é iniciar a animação em cascata, isso é quando a primeira li chegar na metade da animação a segunda começa, dai a terceira inicia quando a segunda estiver na metade e assim vai.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kbneq9uu/1/ Veja se é algo parecido com isso ou é isso que você quer.

Comment: opa isso serve e muito bem obrigado ^^

Comment: Então vou postar como resposta...

Comment: então eu adicionei no meu html e não funcionou :(

Comment: É porquê eu fiz em SCSS. Agora na minha resposta compilei e fiz em CSS. Veja...

Comment: qual a diferença de scss e css?

Comment: Nenhuma praticamente. SCSS, LESS são pré-processadores de CSS. Você escreve o CSS de um jeito diferente. Ele é compilado e se torna um arquivo .css. Dê uma lida nas matérias da internet. É fácil e quando começar a usar nunca mais irá parar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.img-minibox {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -40px;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
}

a:first-child li {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}
a:nth-child(2) li {
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
a:nth-child(3) li {
  animation-delay: 0.8s;
}
a:last-child li {
  animation-delay: 1.1s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul>

  <a href=''>
    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
      <div class='img-minibox'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x150' class='img-responsive'>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href=''>
    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
      <div class='img-minibox'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/200x200' class='img-responsive'>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href=''>
    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
      <div class='img-minibox'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x250' class='img-responsive'>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href=''>
    <li class='col-sm-3 animated slideInDown'>
      <div class='img-minibox'>
        <img src='http://placehold.it/350x250' class='img-responsive'>
      </div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: perfeito muito obrigado ^^